# ERROR: "Cygwin GCC" that is unsupported on this system

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to create my first C++ exeecutable using Eclipse IDE (using Windows 7). I am getting the following error while building.

How to correct it?

> ERROR:: couldn't get context of main thread, error 998

Info: Configuration "Debug" uses **tool-chain "Cygwin GCC" that is unsupported on this system**, attempting to build anyway.

make all

'Building file: ../src/LestTest.cpp'
[sig] C:\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\bin\make.exe 1000 (0) call_handler: couldn't get context of main thread, error 998

Bash

[image]

Path Environment variable has the following

> C:\cygwin\bin\

Please see the following screenshots from eclipse

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well my advice for C++ and Eclipse would be, don't bother. But since you're trying the question that needs answering first is, do you believe that you have cygwin installed on your system? Secondly, have you included g++ as part of that cygwin installation?

Comment: @jahhaj I believe I have installed. Please see the BASH screenshot

Comment: Well you've changed the screenshot. The latest is showing that you don't have make installed. If you google for your error message it has something to do with a version of bash that has nothing to do cygwin. I would guess that you have conflicting installations of Unix like tools.

Comment: @jahhaj What need to be done for the "make" ?

Comment: You install it from cygwin. But as I said above it seems you have some conflict, multiple versions of bash, g++ etc installed. You need to sort that out. Alternatively you could just use Visual C++ Express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a test with "Bash" as mentioned in [Error: Program "make" not found in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817994/error-program-make-not-found-in-path)

Make sure that the Bash result is pointing to the location mentioned in Cygwin

Build the code - this result in a binary folder

Run the application

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you do appear to have Cygwin installed, but it appears to be an ancient version. I suggest that you uninstall the version you have, download the setup program from [here](http://www.cygwin.com/) and install the current version. Be sure to select g++ to be installed.

UPDATE: On second thoughts, if you don't have a specific requirement to use Cygwin, it might be easier to use MinGW instead. Installation instructions are [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/InstallationHOWTOforMinGW).