# Error: Program "make" not found in PATH

Tags: c++, eclipse, window, eclipse-cdt

I have the following error in Eclipse CDT (using Windows 7). How to correct it?

> Error: Program "make" not found in PATH
>   PATH=[C:\cygwin\bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.6.0/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.6.0/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.6.0/lib/i386;C:\Program Files\WinRAR;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\cygwin\bin\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$EX00.502\eclipse]

Path Environment variable has the following

> C:\cygwin\bin\

BASH
[image]

Comment: This is related to [Where do I get make for cygwin?](http://superuser.com/q/154418) on superuser.com.

Answer (score 3):

You should install make package in cygwin. To do this execute cygwin setup.exe and when the window of packages opened, search make and install it. This is gonna solve your problem i think

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `make` which is used for processing Makefiles to build programs.

Also to me it seems that this is more related to superuser.com, [here](https://superuser.com/questions/154418/where-do-i-get-make-for-cygwin) is a similar question.